# How can I simulate user interaction (key press event) in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, keyevent, qkeyevent

I need to simulate <kbd>Enter</kbd> key event in Qt. How can I do this?

Answer (score 27):

The correct answer might be this:

```cpp
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (receiver, event);
```

In fact, there are no matching function for call to:

```cpp
QtKeyEvent::QtKeyEvent(Type type, int key)
```

but there is:

```cpp
QtKeyEvent::QtKeyEvent(Type type, int key, Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers)
```

Comment: Should be Qt::NoModifier not Qt::NoModifiers.

Comment: It's important to simulate a KeyPress followed by a KeyReleased because there are objects that process something when the key is released. An example is a QWebView running a JavaScript that handles keyUp events. They won't be generated unless you post a KeyRelease event.

Comment: You can also use `shareEvent` if you'd rather the `QKeyEvent` be allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 23):

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (receiver, event)
```