# How to simulate the cancel button pressing for QFileDialog?

Tags: qt, button, qt4, simulation, qfiledialog

How to simulate the cancel button pressing for `QFileDialog`?

Searching doesn't help much here as most threads (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2035310/2589776)) are talking about simulating key pressing for QT application, not particularly for a `QFileDialog`.

P.S.: I want to do this because currently I am using a library created by others, the code somehow depend on the `QFileDialog` to open. It is becoming very annoying if needing user intersection each time by manually pressing the cancel button.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the library use static methods like `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` or `QFileDialog` objects? Can you acquire `QFileDialog` pointer? Can you change the library code? Do you want to cancel dialog immediately after showing it (or prevent showing it) or at any time after showing?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I can acquire the `QFileDialog` pointer and have the right to change the library code. It'll be better if I can cancel the dialog at any time after showing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the library uses `QFileDialog` as shown in the documentation:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
QStringList fileNames;
if (dialog.exec()) {
  fileNames = dialog.selectedFiles();
}
```

In that case you can just hide it. It causes `exec()` to return `QDialog::Rejected` immediately:

```
fileDialog->hide();
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for quick response. But it doesn't work for me, it still shows the dialog without closing automatically. Is there anything related to the dialog calling function `getSaveFileName()`?

Comment: `getSaveFileName` is a static function that uses native file dialog. I'm not even sure that `QFileDialog` object is created when it's used. At least on Windows it blocks event loop, so I can't execute anything while the dialog is open. I think it's not possible to do something with this kind of dialog. If you can change the code, you should replace all `QFileDialog` calls to a custom wrapper that will behave as you wish.