# Generate a keyPressEvent/Input

Tags: c++, qt, input, keyevent, qkeyevent

I need to generate an input of my keyboard, because I have an event attached to it. I tried to call this but without success:

```cpp
keyPressEvent(Qt::Key_Delete);
```

Is there a way to generate this keyPressEvent ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I simulate user interaction (key press event) in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035310/how-can-i-simulate-user-interaction-key-press-event-in-qt)

Comment: @Merlin069 Thank you, it's indeed a duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to use a `QkeyEvent`.

Are you using Qt4 or Qt5?

Have a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035547/3751213

It might help.

Or, if you are using linux then `xte` would be great. It is included in `xautomation`.

```
xte 'key Delete'
```

Look here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte