# How to press a key in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT.

How can I press and release a button in Qt ?

In java I do the below program to control key events ?

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

I want to press a key in keyboard programatically.

But , How can I do the same thing in QT ?

Comment: @scopchanov Can you explain in detail ?

Comment: No , I want to press a key in keyboard programatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52619955/5366641

Answer (score 0):

You can either create `QKeyEvent` and send them to the application using `QApplication::sendEvent()`. Or if you want higher level API, you can build your application with `QtTest` module and use `keyClick` functions. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtest.html

Comment: I want to press a key in keyboard programatically. Can you explain in detail ? or give some sample codes

Comment: For example `QTest::keyClick(qApp->focusWidget(), Qt::Key_Enter);` simulates pressing Enter key on the focused widget.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, key presses are handled by the [Event System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/eventsandfilters.html). Like other languages/frameworks events are encapsulated in an object, in Qt's case, [QEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qevent.html#details). All subclasses of QObject have a virtual [`QObject::event(QEvent *e)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#event) method to handle event objects sent to it. This method does not directly handle the event, but calls the object's appropriate event handler based on the [`QEvent::Type`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qevent.html#Type-enum) enum. In the case of key presses, the `QEvent::type()` method returns `QEvent::KeyPress`.

While most events are handled internally without programmer intervention, you may send events manually using the [QCoreApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html) class or its subclass [QGuiApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html). An instance of one of these classes is typically instantiated in the boilerplate `main.cpp` file created when you generate a new project with Qt Creator. These classes have access to the methods [`QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent), which sends an event directly to receiver, and [`QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event, int priority)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent), which sends the event to Qt's event queue to be processed later.

I've created a project to demonstrate this functionality. This app just displays a plain rectangle which can be either red or blue. The rectangle only switches colors when it receives a [`QKeyEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qkeyevent.html) indicating that the C key was pressed. Below the rectangle is a button which programmatically produces this event and sends it to the rectangle's widget. The project went on a bit long and is a bit messy, but I hope it helps some.

`main.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    // Here I modify the boilerplate code to allow MainWindow w to have access 
    // to QApplication a so that a widget in MainWindow w can use postEvent()
    MainWindow w(nullptr, &a);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

`mainwindow.h`

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr, QCoreApplication* app = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>

#include "keypressacceptor.h"
#include "keypressgenerator.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, QCoreApplication *app)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    KeyPressAcceptor* kpa = new KeyPressAcceptor(this);
    KeyPressGenerator* kpg = new KeyPressGenerator();
    kpg->registerReceiver(kpa);
    kpg->registerApp(app);

    layout->addWidget(kpa);
    layout->addWidget(kpg);

    centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

`keypressacceptor.h`

```
#include <QWidget>

class KeyPressAcceptor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit KeyPressAcceptor(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    bool handleKeyPress(const int &key);

protected:
    bool event(QEvent *event) override;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

signals:
private:
    QColor m_color;

};
```

`keypressacceptor.cpp`

```
#include "keypressacceptor.h"

#include <QEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QPainter>

KeyPressAcceptor::KeyPressAcceptor(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}
    , m_color(QColor(220, 20, 20))
{
    // Setting focus policy so that the widget can accept focus.
    // This is necessary to process key press events.
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
}

bool KeyPressAcceptor::handleKeyPress(const int &key)
{
    // This method performs some arbitrary action, in this case changing a
    // color, to indicate that a key press has been processed.
    switch (key) {
    case Qt::Key_C:

        // If the "C" key was pressed, switch m_color
        if (m_color == QColor(220, 20, 20)) {
            m_color = QColor(20, 20, 220);
        } else {
            m_color = QColor(220, 20, 20);
        }

        // Call update() to tell Qt to repaint this widget once Qt has entered
        // the main event loop
        update();
        return true;

    default:

        return false;
    }
}

bool KeyPressAcceptor::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::KeyPress:

        // If the received event is of type QEvent::KeyPress, then cast the
        // variable event to type QKeyEvent*, then use the event's key()
        // method to pass as an argument to this class's handleKeyPress()
        // method.
        return handleKeyPress(static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key());

        // Note! This overrides QWidget's default behavior upon receiving a
        // QKeyEvent event

    default:

        // Otherwise, be sure to use the class's superclass to process any
        // other events.
        return QWidget::event(event);
    }
}

void KeyPressAcceptor::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    // Don't need to use the event parameter in this implementation.
    Q_UNUSED(event)

    // Want to draw a rectangle centered in the widget whose height is half
    // the widget's height and whose width is half the widget's width.
    // The color of the rectangle is determined by m_color.

    // First define the rectangle using the height and width properties of
    // QWidget to determine the rectangle's height, width, and coordinates of
    // top left corner.
    QRect rect(width() / 4, height() / 4,  // Coordinates of top left corner
               width() / 2, height() / 2); // Width and height

    // Create a QPainter object to paint with
    QPainter painter(this);

    // Set pen and brush for rectangle's outline and fill respectively.
    painter.setPen(QColor(0,0,0)); // Black 1px pen
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(m_color)); // Solid fill of color m_color

    // Draw the rectangle
    painter.drawRect(rect);
}
```

`keypressgenerator.h`

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>

class KeyPressGenerator : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit KeyPressGenerator(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void registerApp(QCoreApplication* app);
    void registerReceiver(QObject* receiver);

public slots:
    void generateKeyPress();

private:
    QCoreApplication* m_app;
    QObject* m_receiver;
};
```

`keypressgenerator.cpp`

```
#include "keypressgenerator.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QKeyEvent>

KeyPressGenerator::KeyPressGenerator(QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton{parent}
    , m_app(nullptr)
    , m_receiver(nullptr)
{
    setText("Push Button to Send C Key Press");

    // Connect clicked signal to generateKeyPress so when button is clicked
    // a programmatically generated keypress is sent to m_receiver
    connect(this, &KeyPressGenerator::clicked,
            this, &KeyPressGenerator::generateKeyPress);
}

void KeyPressGenerator::registerApp(QCoreApplication *app)
{
    m_app = app;
}

void KeyPressGenerator::registerReceiver(QObject *receiver)
{
    m_receiver = receiver;
}

void KeyPressGenerator::generateKeyPress()
{
    if (m_app == nullptr || m_receiver == nullptr) return;

    // Generate the key press event. Check documentation for an explanation of
    // the constructor's parameters.
    QKeyEvent* event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_C, Qt::NoModifier);

    m_app->postEvent(m_receiver, event);
}
```

Comment: No, I want to press a key in keyboard programatically.

Comment: @Jeeva can you explain how "press a key in keyboard programatically" is different from the functionality demonstrated inside the `KeyPressGenerator::generateKeyPress()` method in this answer?

Comment: I want to press a key using function. If I call a function a key will press. eg. If I want to press key "a" then I will call a function then the function's process is press the key. `fun(){ //press c }` how to write a program in qt for this ?